# os x 10.11 use port install gcc5 error?

Tags: macos, gcc, port

The error information is:

```
--->  Computing dependencies for gcc5
--->  Cleaning gcc5
--->  Scanning binaries for linking errors
--->  No broken files found.
```

How to fixed it?

Answer (score 1):

The pertinent phrase is: `no broken files found.` That typically means the installation has succeeded. Try `port select --list gcc` to see the available gcc ports.

Use `port select --set <variant>` to set a particular gcc installation as active. e.g., `mp-gcc5`

You can also try `gcc -v` on the command line to ensure you're using the compiler that you expect. You *might* need to `[re]hash` the shell - though I've never experienced this issue.